# angular - set background without using ViewEncapsulation.None

Tags: css, angular

I'm having trouble trying to understand why I am unable to set the background of my component properly without resorting to `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Right now, while using `ViewEncapsulation.None`, my styles are:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

html,body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(25deg, #b24592, #f15f79) no-repeat;
}
```

The template:

```
<body class="login-shop-background">
    /* stuff goes here */
</body>
```

While using `ViewEncapsulation.None`, the result is what I want:

[image]

However, once I remove `ViewEncapsulation.None`, the result is the following (notice the placeholder font in the input also changes):

[image]

I can't wrap my head as to why this is happening. I really don't want to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` because it affects some of the element styles in different components. Could someone help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Angular View Encapsulation encapsulates only what's rendered from the component. `html` and `body` aren't rendered in the component, so those selectors will never match if you try and render them with ViewEncapsulation.

It turns the selectors into something like `html[hash],body[hash]` which won't match since those attributes don't exist outside the component.

Unfortunately, the [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector doesn't exist yet, so there's no easy way to conditionally apply styles onto parent elements based on the children.